# Refreshing Windows DHCP Server reservation active/inactive state

Tags: windows-server-2016, dhcp-server

I have a Windows DHCP server with a number of reservations.  These all seem to work correctly (in that the addresses are correctly distributed) but, somehow, the Active/Inactive state of these has become corrupted in the Leases view on the DHCP MMC.

Machines that I *know* are not plugged in are showing up as Active, making it very difficult to see at-a-glance which machines are on-site or not (at least, not without additional tools/scans -- we *have* these, they are off-topic).

Said machines have been off-site for far longer than the scope's timeout, but nothing seems to revert these back to Inactive.  I suspect this is because they pulled out, rather than doing a clean DHCP release.

Newly-added reservations seem to be OK, but I'm not going to delete and recreate these, even with a `netsh` dump/exec.  Is there any non-destructive way to reset this state?

Answer (score -1):

Set supported type to DHCP only